# Density of states for fermions for temperatures other than absolute zero

Tags: statistical-mechanics, temperature, fermions, density-of-states

Let's say I wanted to calculate the density of states for $\mathrm{2D}$ Fermions with an energy dispersion of $E_F=ck^6$ at $T=0$

The process would be quite mathematically simple. I'd take the distribution, apply the delta function and calculate the integral, that is:
$$\frac{4\pi V}{4\pi^2}\int_0^{\infty}k\,\delta(E-ck^6)\,\mathrm{d}k $$ I'd then find the points in which the function inside the $\delta$ vanishes, that is:
$$ z(k) = 0\\ k_0=\left(\frac{E}{c}\right)^{1/6} $$
and find the derivation:
$$\lvert \frac{\partial z}{\partial k}\rvert$$
And plugging it back into the integral I'd get the correct result for $g(E)$
My question is: What difference would it make, changing the temperature from absolute zero to some other temperature? (and the physical interpretation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In principle, the density of states for a fermionic system must be given as:
$$
D(E) = \sum_{\sigma} \delta(E-E_\sigma)\times 2  \times f(E,T)
$$
Where $\sigma$ represents a particular eigen state of the system (and $E_\sigma$ its eigenvalue) and $f(E,T)$ represents the fermi dirac distribution.

The reason for this is that after finding the energy levels we need to ascribe an occupancy number(also knowns as occupation probability) to each of them. At zero Temperature, that would be that the electrons occupy each energy level with occupation number 1(because of Pauli principle) if the energy is less than the Fermi level $E_f$. The factor 2 is there because

For energies greater than the Fermi level $E_f$, this occupancy is 0. So, all energy states in the summation that have energy greater than $E_f$ do not contribute to the density of states.

At finite temperature, the Fermi level is sort of "smeared" and each energy has an occupation number between 0 and 1.

I hope I answered your question! If you have any further questions, please let me know!

Comment: So in a nutshell, the $T=0$ is there to specify the Fermi energy. At different temperatures we would have a different Fermi level and wouldn't be able to find it simply by using the method in my question?

Comment: @DominikCar yeah, somewhat true. So the Fermi energy is actually just the chemical potential of the system at T =0. At some finite temperature, the distribution changes from a step-like function to a distorted one as some particles have energy greater than the chemical potential.